# Object(...) is not a function on useRef hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Problem.
Every time i try to use useRef it throws an error that ***Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function***.

I am trying to make a threejs scene using react hooks but getting this error always. But in past i have done it using **class based components**, there it was working correctly

Here is the code

```
    const Updated = () => {
      var earthMesh, freedomMesh;
      var scene;
      var result;
      const mount = useRef(null);       //error here
      const controls = useRef(null);

      const createMe = () => {
        const width = mount.current.clientWidth;
        const height = mount.current.clientHeight;

        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xdddddd);
        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, width / height, 1, 5000);
        camera.position.set(0, 25, 25);
      };

      useEffect(() => {
        createMe();
      }, []);

      return (
        <div>
          <div
            style={{
              width: "600px",
              height: "470px",
            }}
            ref={mount}
          />
        </div>
      );
    };

    export default Updated;
```

Comment: What's your react version? and react-dom?

Comment: I just check its an old one.  its 16.5.2, how do i upgrade it with other packages also?

Comment: How are you importing `useRef`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with your version `16.5.2`. [Hooks were introduced into `16.8`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1680-february-6-2019).

To upgrade to latest via node do:
`npm update <package-name>`

Comment: im trying to update but it returns me back without performing any operation. Here i have added the photo => https://ibb.co/wB3gjKC

Comment: Does your `package.json` look the same as well or was the verision updated? You're also going to have to install the packages after you update with `npm i`.

Comment: Thanks for help, i had to restart vscode to see the updated packages